# Understanding basic functionality of Android Spinner

Tags: android-studio, android-spinner

I'm absolutely new to Android, & generally a non-tech person. I have two questions:

Question 1:
I'm using the expression "android:onClick" within XML definition of a BUTTON to initiate an activity.
What is an equivalent activity once an item has been selected from a SPINNER?
I looked very hard at previous questions but couldn't find a similar question.

Question 2:
After a BUTTON click, I'm fetching the BUTTON id using the expression "View.getId()". Will same expression work if I wish to know the text selected by user from the SPINNER?

Thanks